# Password was required to mount drive but my password didn't work (while still working elsewhere)

Tags: fedora, mount, root

Ok guys, me again... I had to reinstall Fedora 22, going well for the most part.

Problem is mounting and accessing my Win 7 partition.

For some reason when I try to access it from graphic file manager it asks for a password saying it requires authentication, but then my password doesn't work. At all. I even tried my root password. I even tried every other password it might possibly be. It asks specifically for my user password though and it just doesn't work. In every other situation my password works ( sudo, log in, etc ).

So I had to mount as root by way of command line. This wasn't happening to me before, all I had to do was click on it and it mounted for me. Any thoughts? I have a 2TB external that's a windows format just the same and I'm not having a problem with that one. I would like to be able to easily access it again. And I'd like to know why my password doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it accessible all the time, chuck a line in your `/etc/fstab`. If you've already mounted it manually from the command line you should have all the settings worked out.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=da5b64eb-1aeb-4f15-ae63-f98a3d8488ac /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

You just need to add another line with your partition information and where you want it mounted. Note you don't need to know the UUID of the partition, you can use a formation like `/dev/sdb1`. The last 2 numbers should both be `0`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. And interestingly enough after a reboot I no longer had the problem with my password authorization, I cacn mount and unmount it from the file manager. The fstab mod works great.